# using Sessions with DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, session-cookies, tomcat8

So I have a maven / spring application running on tomcat 8. I'm playing around with storing the sessions in dynmao db. There are a few reasons why I want to do this but i'll spare you the details.

I've been following this guide pretty religiously https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html#java-dg-tomcat-sess-manage-with-ddb but my data does not seem to be being sent to the dynamoDB table I set up.

So what i've done.

First I downloaded this jar:

```
aws-dynamodb-session-tomcat-2.0.4.jar
```

and moved it to my lib folder.

Then I set up my context.xml like:

```
className="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.sessionmanager.DynamoDBSessionManager"
        awsAccessKey="mykey"
        awsSecretKey="mysecertKey"
        regionId="us-east-1"
        createIfNotExist="true" />
```

These apps are on EC2 instances so I skiped the ECB step. Next I set up a DBB table that looks like:

```
Table name  Tomcat_SessionState
Primary partition key   sessionId (String)
```

But when I restart my app and try and login I don't see anything geting posted there..

I've been tailing my catalina.out but no luck there either. Another note on this I don't see anything about DBB in my catalina.out strange.

Am I missing a common step here?

UPDATE:

When I start my app it creates the needed table. Just can't seem to get it to send the session id's out there. I wonder if a code change needs to be made to support this feature? I thought it supported any forum of sessions. 
Edited by: dennis93 on Mar 8, 2018 2:13 PM

I see something like this in my log:
dynamo-session-manager-expired-sesion-reaper

Answer (score 1):

Dynamo DB Tomcat Session Management Support is dropped. Ref: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=275425

Answer (score 0):

When I was experimenting with the AWS DynamoDB session manager, I experienced an unexplainable effect where writes of session data into DynamoDB would ONLY occur if the Manager is declared inside the global context.xml, i.e. within $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml

The data has to be written to your DynamoDB table in order to persist across tomcat process restarts.